# C++ WinAPI. Wrong text display in the listbox

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage

I have a task to create a program which displays a list of descriptors of all windows in the system. I am getting this output:

[image]

Maybe it's wrong encoding?

Here's my code:

```
#include <windows.h>

ATOM RegMyWindowClass(HINSTANCE, LPCTSTR);
HWND hListBox;
HINSTANCE hin;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    WCHAR str[255];
    if (GetWindowTextW(hwnd, str, 255)) {
        if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && (!GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER)))
            SendMessage(hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str);
    }
    return 1;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
    HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Вы кликнули!"), TEXT("событие"), 0);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);  
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        hListBox = CreateWindow("LISTBOX", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_NOTIFY | WS_VSCROLL,
            0, 0, 400, 400, hWnd, (HMENU)1111, hin, NULL);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE         hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR             lpCmdLine,
    int               nCmdShow)
{
    LPCTSTR lpzClass = TEXT("My Window Class!");

    if (!RegMyWindowClass(hInstance, lpzClass))
        return 1;

    RECT screen_rect;
    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &screen_rect); 
    int x = screen_rect.right / 2 - 200;
    int y = screen_rect.bottom / 2 - 200;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(lpzClass, TEXT("Window"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, 400, 400, NULL, NULL,
        hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    EnumWindows(&EnumWindowsProc, 0);
    if (!hWnd) return 2;

    MSG msg = { 0 };   
    int iGetOk = 0;   
    while ((iGetOk = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (iGetOk == -1) return 3;  
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;  
}

ATOM RegMyWindowClass(HINSTANCE hInst, LPCTSTR lpzClassName)
{
    WNDCLASS wcWindowClass = { 0 };
    wcWindowClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wcWindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcWindowClass.hInstance = hInst;
    wcWindowClass.lpszClassName = lpzClassName;
    wcWindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcWindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_APPWORKSPACE;
    return RegisterClass(&wcWindowClass); 
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Try replacing `WCHAR` with `TCHAR` and `GetWindowTextW` with `GetWindowText`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it works! Thank you!

Comment: You should not mix TCHARs and WCHAR and A and W versions of functions. Use `WCHAR` and `W` versions of functions everywhere and make sure you compile with UNICODE enabled.

Comment: Here's some helpful reading: [Working with Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That was a poor suggestion. Modern applications should always use wide strings (and corresponding functions) instead of ANSI compatibility wrappers.

Comment: @VTT if you explicitly use `WCHAR` and `W` functions, there is no need to worry about the `UNICODE` define at all. It only applies to `TCHAR` and `TCHAR`-based functions.

Comment: @VTT I'm not going to re-write OP's entire app. It appears the rest of the program is not using unicode. It's up to OP to fix.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, one should always pay attention to `UNICODE` define even if his code explicitly uses wide chars and `W` functions because (1) not all the stuff in Windows SDK header has explicit `A` and `W` variants so the only available name depends on correctly defined `UNICODE` macro (for example NT Privilege names, such as `SE_CREATE_TOKEN_NAME`) (2) this macro may be utilized in third party libraries.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp The problem is that without properly converting everything to use wide chars this application will still fail to display text from windows that contain Unicode text not convertible to current locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are compiling your project for ANSI, where `TCHAR` is an alias for `CHAR`, and are thus creating an ANSI-based ListBox, but you are sending Unicode strings to it.  That is why you are seeing garbage in the output.  You need to send ANSI strings to the ListBox, eg:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && (!GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER)))
        CHAR str[255] = {};
        if (GetWindowTextA(hwnd, str, 255)) {
            SendMessage(hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str);
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && (!GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER))) {
        CHAR str[255] = {};
        if (IsWindowUnicode(hwnd)) {
            WCHAR wstr[255] = {}; 
            int len = GetWindowTextW(hwnd, wstr, 255);
            if (len) {
                len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr, len+1, str, 255, NULL, NULL);
            }
            if (!len) {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        else if (!GetWindowTextA(hwnd, str, 255)) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        SendMessage(hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

That being said, you are mixing ANSI, Unicode, and `TCHAR` APIs.  You need to pick *1* API style and stick with it for everything, don't mix them (unless you ABSOLUTELY have to).

Since the majority of the code you have shown is already using `TCHAR`, then you can use `TCHAR` for everything (though, you really shouldn't, since `TCHAR` is meant for backwards compatibility with Win9x/ME which nobody uses anymore, and was intended only to help people migrate their code to Unicode. Modern code should not be using `TCHAR` at all):

```
#include <windows.h>

ATOM RegMyWindowClass(HINSTANCE, LPCTSTR);
HWND hListBox;
HINSTANCE hin;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && (!GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER))) {
        TCHAR str[255];
        if (GetWindowText(hwnd, str, 255)) {
            SendMessage(hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str);
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
    HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        // this is one case where it doesn't make sense to use TCHAR
        MessageBoxW(hWnd, L"Вы кликнули!", L"событие", 0);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);  
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        hListBox = CreateWindow(TEXT("LISTBOX"), TEXT(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_NOTIFY | WS_VSCROLL,
            0, 0, 400, 400, hWnd, (HMENU)1111, hin, NULL);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE         hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR             lpCmdLine,
    int               nCmdShow)
{
    LPCTSTR lpzClass = TEXT("My Window Class!");

    if (!RegMyWindowClass(hInstance, lpzClass))
        return 1;

    RECT screen_rect;
    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &screen_rect); 
    int x = screen_rect.right / 2 - 200;
    int y = screen_rect.bottom / 2 - 200;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(lpzClass, TEXT("Window"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, 400, 400, NULL, NULL,
        hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    EnumWindows(&EnumWindowsProc, 0);
    if (!hWnd) return 2;

    MSG msg = { 0 };   
    int iGetOk = 0;   
    while ((iGetOk = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (iGetOk == -1) return 3;  
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;  
}

ATOM RegMyWindowClass(HINSTANCE hInst, LPCTSTR lpzClassName)
{
    WNDCLASS wcWindowClass = { 0 };
    wcWindowClass.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;
    wcWindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcWindowClass.hInstance = hInst;
    wcWindowClass.lpszClassName = lpzClassName;
    wcWindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcWindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_APPWORKSPACE;
    return RegisterClass(&wcWindowClass); 
}
```

Otherise, use Unicode for everything:

```
#include <windows.h>

ATOM RegMyWindowClass(HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR);
HWND hListBox;
HINSTANCE hin;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && (!GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER))) {
        WCHAR str[255];
        if (GetWindowTextW(hwnd, str, 255)) {
            SendMessage(hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str);
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
    HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        MessageBoxW(hWnd, L"Вы кликнули!", L"событие", 0);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);  
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        hListBox = CreateWindowW(L"LISTBOX", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_NOTIFY | WS_VSCROLL,
            0, 0, 400, 400, hWnd, (HMENU)1111, hin, NULL);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE         hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR             lpCmdLine,
    int               nCmdShow)
{
    LPCWSTR lpzClass = L"My Window Class!";

    if (!RegMyWindowClass(hInstance, lpzClass))
        return 1;

    RECT screen_rect;
    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &screen_rect); 
    int x = screen_rect.right / 2 - 200;
    int y = screen_rect.bottom / 2 - 200;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(lpzClass, L"Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, 400, 400, NULL, NULL,
        hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    EnumWindows(&EnumWindowsProc, 0);
    if (!hWnd) return 2;

    MSG msg = { 0 };   
    int iGetOk = 0;   
    while ((iGetOk = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (iGetOk == -1) return 3;  
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;  
}

ATOM RegMyWindowClass(HINSTANCE hInst, LPCWSTR lpzClassName)
{
    WNDCLASSW wcWindowClass = { 0 };
    wcWindowClass.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;
    wcWindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcWindowClass.hInstance = hInst;
    wcWindowClass.lpszClassName = lpzClassName;
    wcWindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcWindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_APPWORKSPACE;
    return RegisterClassW(&wcWindowClass); 
}
```

Or, stick with ANSI for everything, if you need to maintain compatibility with existing code logic elsewhere in your project:

```
#include <windows.h>

ATOM RegMyWindowClass(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR);
HWND hListBox;
HINSTANCE hin;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && (!GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER))) {
        CHAR str[255];
        if (GetWindowTextA(hwnd, str, 255)) {
            SendMessage(hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str);
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
    HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        // this is one case where it doesn't make sense to use ANSI
        MessageBoxW(hWnd, L"Вы кликнули!", L"событие", 0);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);  
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        hListBox = CreateWindowA("LISTBOX", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_NOTIFY | WS_VSCROLL,
            0, 0, 400, 400, hWnd, (HMENU)1111, hin, NULL);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE         hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR             lpCmdLine,
    int               nCmdShow)
{
    LPCSTR lpzClass = "My Window Class!";

    if (!RegMyWindowClass(hInstance, lpzClass))
        return 1;

    RECT screen_rect;
    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &screen_rect); 
    int x = screen_rect.right / 2 - 200;
    int y = screen_rect.bottom / 2 - 200;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowA(lpzClass, "Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, 400, 400, NULL, NULL,
        hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    EnumWindows(&EnumWindowsProc, 0);
    if (!hWnd) return 2;

    MSG msg = { 0 };   
    int iGetOk = 0;   
    while ((iGetOk = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (iGetOk == -1) return 3;  
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;  
}

ATOM RegMyWindowClass(HINSTANCE hInst, LPCSTR lpzClassName)
{
    WNDCLASSA wcWindowClass = { 0 };
    wcWindowClass.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;
    wcWindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcWindowClass.hInstance = hInst;
    wcWindowClass.lpszClassName = lpzClassName;
    wcWindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcWindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_APPWORKSPACE;
    return RegisterClassA(&wcWindowClass); 
}
```